# remote logging in redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

```js
export default async (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
//... Many other cases
    CASE 'A':
    CASE 'B':
    CASE 'C':
    CASE 'D':
    CASE 'E':
    {
      //call http request for logging purpose
      return { ...state, isLoadingFlag: true };
    }
   //Yes there is default case
  }
}
```

I have the above reducer that makes `isLoadingFlag` true. I'm wondering which one hits the case, so what I do is, add a remote logging functionality within the `reducer`. But weird enough, it actually messed up the state? because I can't see my loading flag showing anymore.

I don't understand why this happened because all reducer care is returning a state object, theoratically speaking, it should work even we add remote network request in it isnt it?

**Extra Information:**

Reason for the above setup is because somehow my mac couldn't detect Huawei phone in adb mode so I couldn't perform debugging on specific device.

Comment: reducer is not for logging. it's for updating the redux store.

Comment: @codekaizer: Of course it's not. But I was asking because from my understanding, as long as we returning a new state, it should be alright

Comment: "as long as we returning a new state, it should be alright", do you have a default case? what is the case to set `isLoadingFlag` to `false`?

Comment: @codekaizer: I didnt include the whole reducer. But thanks as I already found answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to remove `async` from you function initialization because reducers have to be synchronized. In your case the reducer returns a Promise because of `async`.

Comment: Yes you're right! I've added the `async` because naturally added `await` for network request. But since just a simple logging I can just remove the `await` for network request. Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Redux's reducer should be pure function, not `async` one.

I think you are using reducer for the wrong purpose. [Reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) is used to describe how the application state should be changed based on the dispatched action.

To do remote logging, please use [middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) or async dispatch library like `redux-think` or `redux-saga`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use [Redux-Sagas](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and there you can define 1 saga which listen all actions or 1 saga for each action. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Reducer functions should be pure functions. You can resolve your async operations in actions and dispatch or use Redux middleware(redux-thunk) to handle async operations.

Please refer https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers